# Python urllib or requests library get stuck to open certain URLs?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, urllib

I am trying to send HTTP GET request to certain website, for example, `https://www.united.com`, but it get stuck with no response.
Here is the code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = 'https://www.united.com'
resp = urlopen(url,timeout=10 )
```

Every time, it goes timeout. But the same code works for other URLs, for example, `https://www.aa.com`.
So I wonder what is behind `https://www.united.com` that keeps me from getting the HTTP request through. Thank you!

Update:
Adding a request header still doesn't work for this site:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = 'https://www.united.com'
req = urllib.request.Request(
    url, 
    data=None, 
    headers={
        'User-Agent':' Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36'
    }
)
resp = urlopen(req,timeout=3 )
```

Answer (score 0):

The server of united.com might be only responding to certain user-agent strings or request headers and blocking for others. You have to send certain headers or user-agent string which are allowed by their server. This depends upon website to website who want to add some more security to their applications so they are very specific about user-agents like which resource is trying to access them.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question! But when I added the request header, ` headers={
        'User-Agent':' Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36'
    }`, it still doesn't work...